# weird handling of double quotes when using cmd /c "echo"

Tags: cmd, escaping

I'm trying to escape some calls in bat file and I found out that I don't understand even on simple example the weird handling of double quotes:

Try

```
cmd /c "echo " "%TEMP%"                   rem this gives: " "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp
cmd /c "echo" "%TEMP%"                    rem this gives: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
cmd /c "echo beg "TEMP" %TEMP%"           rem this gives: beg "TEMP" C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp
cmd /c "echo beg ^"TEMP^" %TEMP%"         rem this gives: beg "TEMP" C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp
cmd /c "echo beg \"TEMP\" %TEMP%"         rem this gives: beg \"TEMP\" C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Just open command prompt (cmd.exe) and paste code.
The results are the same when copy/paste to cmd.exe or running a bat file.

What I would expect is that `cmd /c "echo beg \"TEMP\" %TEMP%"` should work correcctly. At least according to http://daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WIN .

But I don't understand output from all the samples. Anybody could explain me that behaviour?

---

**Edit**:

The site I'm referencing just explains how arguments are parsed on Windows. E.g. http://daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WINCRULES

What is my expected output? 
I just want to know how that passing of double quotes work.
Later I'd like to construct command lines like this one:

```
pwsh -noprofile -command "produceSomeStringsToFind | % { rg -g testfile* \" $_ some string that ends with quote\\\"" . }"
```

where `rg` is https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep - where the `\" $_ some string that ends with quote\\\""` part is regular expression where I need to escape the quotes.

Comment: I guessed stej, that you didn't really want to know how to `echo` a string which would be visible for a fraction of a second, in a [tag:cmd] window which opens and closes, but I'll be honest, using an old method of running a command line to [tag:powershell] is possibly as far away from your initial question as it possibly could have been.

Comment: Yes, it's far away, you are right. But what I did want was just to understand the basics so that I could build more complex commands. I usually run everything in powershell, but sometimes I need that as bat files like in the example.

Comment: You've got a [tag:powershell] question, and you thought that using the [[tag:batch-file]] tag with a completely unrelated command and task was a good idea, and would clearly get you the answer you needed! Why would you expect that passing an argument from `cmd.exe` to another `cmd.exe` instance, (same parser), and passing an an argument from `cmd.exe` to `powershell.exe`, (different parsers), would be an appropriate way to find your solution?

Comment: BTW, I've deleted your [[tag:batch-file]] tag, as it is unrelated to your question, _the provided powershell command, if run from a [tag:batch-file] would fail_, and added the [[tag:powershell]] one, as it is related.

Comment: The escape key for powershell is the backtick, `` ` ``, the escape key for batch is `^`, the escape key for quotes in batch is another quote, i. g. `"" something ""`, is that enough for you?

Comment: Guys, thanks for your help, but you completely misunderstood my question.

Comment: @Compo I didn't want you to solve my original problem as I'm pretty well awared about PowerShell. But calling PowerShell from batch file means that first parsing rules from `cmd.exe` are used. That's it. That's why it was about `cmd.exe`. The asnwer was provided and it completely covers my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the help text of `cmd /?`:

> ```cmd
> [...]
> If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
> the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
> used to process quote (") characters:
>
>     1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
>         on the command line are preserved:
>
>         - no /S switch
>         - exactly two quote characters
>         - no special characters between the two quote characters,
>           where special is one of: &<>()@^|
>         - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
>           two quote characters
>         - the string between the two quote characters is the name
>           of an executable file.
>
>     2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
>         a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
>         remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
>         any text after the last quote character.
> [...]
> ```

It becomes clear that you are facing the situation explained in section `2.`, because `echo` is not an executable file but an internal command. So if the first character is a `"`, it becomes removed and so becomes the last `"`, and all the other characters are preserved.

---

Now let us go through your command lines. So after being parsed and processed by `cmd /c`:

1. `cmd /c "echo " "%TEMP%"` becomes `echo " "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp`.
2. `cmd /c "echo" "%TEMP%"` becomes `echo" "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp`; then the command `echo"` is tried to be executed, but which is not a valid one, hence it fails.
3. `cmd /c "echo beg "TEMP" %TEMP%"` becomes `echo beg "TEMP" C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp`.
4. `cmd /c "echo beg ^"TEMP^" %TEMP%"` becomes `echo beg "TEMP" C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp`, because escaping with `^` happens even before `cmd /c` is executed, so it receives the already escaped literal `"` characters.
5. `cmd /c "echo beg \"TEMP\" %TEMP%"` becomes `echo beg \"TEMP\" C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp`, because the `\` is nothing special to `cmd`.

---

If you want to output the text `"%TEMP%"` (including the quotes), you could do this:

```cmd
rem // This preserves all quotes, because the first character is not such:
cmd /c echo "%TEMP%"
rem // This removes the outer-most pair of quotes, because the first character is such:
cmd /c "echo "%TEMP%""
rem /* This removes the outer-most pair of quotes too, since `cmd /c` receives the already
rem    escaped `"`; however, this could be useful to hide these quotes from the hosting
rem    `cmd` instance, which avoids issues when `%TEMP%` contains special characters
rem    (like `&` or `^`), which you would otherwise have to individually escape: */
cmd /c ^"echo "%TEMP%"^"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That will really help in the future. My shame I didn't go to help. I thought I'm facing some general parsing rules.